# XSLT: repetitive nodes in the output

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation, saxon

I'm struggling with a simple xsl transformation and I'm not able to find out why I have two elements twice in my output result. Here is my code:

xsl-stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>[{</xsl:text> 
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>}]</xsl:text> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Title">
    <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>        
    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>     
    <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::Title"/>            
    <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>    
</xsl:template>
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Start>
    <Title id="1">
        <Title id="2">Bob</Title>
        <Age>39</Age>
        <Address>
            <Title id="3">10 Idle Lane</Title>
            <City>Yucksville</City>
            <PostalCode>xxxyyy</PostalCode>
        </Address>
    </Title>
    <Title id="4">
        <Title id="5">Bill</Title>
        <Age>39</Age>
        <Title id ="6">
            <Title id="7">10 Idle Lane</Title>
            <City>Yucksville</City>
            <PostalCode>xxxyyy</PostalCode>
            <Title id="8">10 Idle Lane</Title>
        </Title>
        <Title id="9">10 Idle Lane</Title>
    </Title>    
</Start>
```

output:

```
[{
    {1{2}{3}}
    {4{5}{6{7}{8}}{7}{8}{9}}    
}]
```

The elements which I've not expected to have in my output are the last numbers: {8}{9}. I guess it has something to do with the descendant axis selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True, the descendant axis selector selects all children and grandchildren etc.. So you just need to apply templates to children. This should work:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>[{</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>}]</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Title">
    <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
    <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" />
```